# Can't execute PHP in MAMP

Tags: php, mamp

I installed MAMP in my macbook with osx mavericks, all preferences are the defaults.
I copied my test.html to /Applications/MAMP/htdocs and go to `http://localhost:8888/test.html`
and the display is: `one three`

and the test.html file:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>
one
<?php
echo 'two ';
?>
three
</body>
</html>
```

The 'two ' of php doesn't appear, anyone knows why?

Comment: Change your extension to test.php please. :)

Comment: thanks! that solved that problem, but I cant solve other I have xD

Answer (score 1):

Your file is being brought to the browser as an html file.  Your server will look to the file extension (in your case .html) in order to figure out what to send to the browser.  You need to change the extension to .php so your server will run the php code and then send the resulting html doc to your browser.

Answer (score 0):

Another option will be to go to the MAMP folder inside Application, and open httpd.conf (~/Application/MAMP/conf/apache/httpd.conf), then add this to the last line

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .html
```

You will need to restart Apache for the changes to take place. You can do that by going to the MAMP window and then clicking "Stop Servers" and "Start Servers". PHP code will be executed inside .html files afterwards.